# How to use InputStream in Http setEntity?

Tags: java, inputstream, apache-httpcomponents, http-put

I'm using org.apache.http.* and trying to PUT a file. I can do it with the below reference to the actual file, however, I'm looking for a way to do it by passing in an `InputStream`

```
File file = new File("/mytestfile.txt")
HttpPut request = new HttpPut("http://sharepointportal/site/mytestfile.txt");
request.setEntity(new FileEntity(file));
CloseableHttpResponse response =  httpclient.execute(new HttpHost("sharepointportal"), request);
```

[FileEntity](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/FileEntity.html) doesn't seem to have a constructor that supports `InputStream`.

**Question**
How can I `setEntity` for `HttpPut` request with an `InputStream`?

Comment: Have you tried to use the `InputStreamEntity` instead of a `FileEntity`?

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work. When I do `(new InputStreamEntity(is)).getContentLength() ` I get a `-1`. I know my `is` has data in it

Comment: Have you ensured that the file exists on the path? With `File#exist`